# Drawing path between nodes using TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

`TeX Code`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (B) at (2, 3);

  \node[draw,minimum width=10mm] at (A) {};
  \node[draw,minimum width=10mm] at (B) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How such path can be drawn using Tikz?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can make a temporary relative node and use orthogonal identifiers

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node[draw,minimum width=10mm] (A) at (0, 0) {};
  \node[draw,minimum width=10mm] (B) at (2, 3) {};

\draw[->] (A) |- ++(1,-1) |- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

or use `paths.ortho` library of our [qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel) but I don't know the latest status of it. I remember him saying about incompatibility somewhere.