# How to draw this kind of figure in latex?

Tags: graphics

How to draw this kind of figure in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Have a look at `tikz`.

Comment: with tikz the left nodes you can draw with `arrow box` shape, in middle column are rectangles with `rounded corners`, on the right nodes has shape `ellipse`. for details see TikZ & PGF manual, chapter *67 Shape Library*, page 693.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281854/36296 can help. However questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are novice, I made MWE as starting point for your image. Of course, you need to finish it and of course, adopted it to your document ...

[image]

Since I'm familiar with TikZ, I use it for drawing above image. Beside it exist other packages by which you can draw this image.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, chains, positioning, shapes, shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tikzitemize}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new list
\setlist[tikzitemize]{nosep,     % <-- new list setup
                      topsep     = 0pt       ,
                      partopsep  = 0pt       ,
                      leftmargin = *         ,
                      label      = $\bullet$ ,
                      before     = \vspace{-1.5ex},
                     }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 0mm,
  start chain = going below,
    AB/.style = {arrow box, arrow box arrows={east:9mm}, draw,
                 text width=44mm, align=left, inner sep=1mm,
                 on chain},
    RB/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw,
                 text width=44mm, align=left, inner sep=1mm,
                 right=of #1.east arrow tip},
    ES/.style = {ellipse, draw, inner sep=0pt,
                 text width=22mm, align=center},
every edge/.append style = {draw,-Straight Barb}
                    ]
\node (n11) [AB,
             label={[name=l]above:\textbf{zz zzz zzz zzz}}]    
                    {\begin{tikzitemize}
                     \item  xxx
                     \item  xxx
                     \end{tikzitemize}
                     };
\node (n12) [AB]    {\begin{tikzitemize}
                     \item  xxx
                     \item  xxx
                     \end{tikzitemize}
                     };
\node (n13) [AB]    {\begin{tikzitemize}
                     \item  xxx
                     \item  xxx
                     \end{tikzitemize}
                     };
%
\node (n21) [RB=n11,
             label=above:\textbf{zz zzz zzz zzz}]  
                        {\begin{tikzitemize}
                         \item  xxx
                         \item  xxx
                         \end{tikzitemize}
                         };
\node (n22) [RB=n12]    {\begin{tikzitemize}
                         \item  xxx
                         \item  xxx
                         \end{tikzitemize}
                         };
\node (n23) [RB=n13]    {\begin{tikzitemize}
                         \item  xxx
                         \item  xxx
                         \end{tikzitemize}
                         };
%
\node (n31) [ES, right=12mm of n22] {some text in two lines};
%
% label for third column
\node at (l -| n31) {\textbf{yyy yyy yyy yyy}};
%
\draw   (n21.east) edge (n31)
        (n22.east) edge (n31)
        (n23.east) edge (n31);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note, in future you need to provide some code in form of MWE, otherwise is very unlikely that your questions will be answered or even closed as just happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help Zarko, samcarter, dexteritas. I'm novice with latex and with the latex images. I'm sorry for any disagreement. For the next time I will follow the rules of the site. Thanks !!!

Comment: @milena, if above answer help you, please vote it (with clicking up pen on the top left side of answer) and even accept it (by clicking on check mark there). This is the best way to express your "thank you". I'm glad to help you. Happy TeX-ing!